# Merge rows upwards, while missing values in cells of column

Tags: r, merge, rows, na

I have some data read in from a poorly formatted pdf table, where the cells sometimes spans across several pages. This has left me with a dataframe that looks similar to this:

```
company_name <- c("company_a", NA, "company_a", "company_b", "company_b", NA)
text <- c("some_text", "text that should be in the above cell","some_text",  "some_text", "some_text","text that should be in the above cell")
more_text <- c("some_text", "text that should be in the above cell", "some_text",  "some_text", "some_text","text that should be in the above cell")
df <- data.frame(company_name, text, more_text)
```

| company_name | text | more_text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| company_a | some_text | some_text |
| NA | text that should be in the above cell | text that should be in the above cell |
| company_a | some_text | some_text |
| company_b | some_text | some_text |
| company_b | some_text | some_text |
| NA | text that should be in the above cell | text that should be in the above cell |

How could I merge the rows that have a missing value where "company_name" should be, so it looks more like this and also loop it over all rows that start with NA:

| company_name | text | more_text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| company_a | some_text + text that should be in the above cell | some_text + text that should be in the above cell |
| company_a | some_text | some_text |
| company_b | some_text | some_text |
| company_b | some_text + text that should be in the above cell | some_text + text that should be in the above cell |

I've tried the `unheadr` package, but I can't seem to figure out the correct function to use.

Edit: re-did the example for more clarity

Comment: what is the condition for collapse_b with company_b and not company_a?

Comment: The dataset itself has multiple entries from several companies, and the frequency of NAs depend on chance. Maybe the example was a bit unclear, I'll edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a logical column based on the NA elements (`ind`), then create the 'grp' by converting the 'ind' or (`|`) the `lead` of that column to numeric index with `rleid`, use `fill` to replace the `NA` elements with the previous non-NA in 'company_name, then use the grouping column and `summarise` `across` the other columns by `paste`ing the elements together

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
   mutate(ind = is.na(company_name), 
       grp = rleid(ind|lead(ind))) %>%
    fill(company_name) %>% 
    group_by(company_name, grp) %>% 
    summarise(across(contains('text'), str_c, collapse=" + "), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  company_name text                                              more_text                                        
#  <chr>        <chr>                                             <chr>                                            
#1 company_a    some_text + text that should be in the above cell some_text + text that should be in the above cell
#2 company_a    some_text                                         some_text                                        
#3 company_b    some_text                                         some_text                                        
#4 company_b    some_text + text that should be in the above cell some_text + text that should be in the above cell
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(company_name = company_a, text, more_text)
```

Comment: How would I go about making ```summarise(across(contains('text'), str_c, collapse=" + "), .groups = 'drop')``` more general, grabbing any column and any row that meets the logical condition in ```ìnd``` ?

Comment: @fiskdill  If you use `across(everything(),` it grabs all the rest of the columns.  I specified `text` as your input showed only those columns that are specific.  You may also use `matches` or other select_helpers to specify columns